# Logging back takes users to the SharePointOnline root site instead of the Intranet in IE

Tags: sharepoint-online, login, ie-11

We have created a separate site collection for company's intranet and has set it is as homepage for all the users.

We are experiencing below issue, after inactivity of say 20 mins, when the user log back in, it takes them to the SharePoint Online root site (team site) instead of the intranet.  How can I change it?  Is there any settings?

Scenario explained:
Logged in to https://cccc.sharepoint.com/sites/publish/....  which is also set as the Homepage in IE.

When the user logs out, after 20 mins of inactivity, when the user logins back to office 365, their homepage is https://ccc.sharepoint.com/Sitepages/home.aspx.

We want them always to go to the company's intranet.

Comment: Have you tried in other browsers? Or is that only IE specific?